# Using MySQLi together with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Hie, Is it possible to have a registration page that uses PDO and the rest of other pages of my application use MySQLi?I have read that PDO is good technology as opposed to MySQLi so i would like to learn it gradually.

Comment: It is possible, but out of curiousity, why do you want to use two different technologies?

Comment: why would you wanna do that?

Comment: @PhpDev-I need to move from mysqli to PDO. When i started, I was introduced to mysqli  but through reading  articles, comments and or answers here on stack-overflow, it became more clear to me that PDO was something  I should consider learning. Since  I have an application already using mysqli i need to translate everything to PDO and my starting point is the user registration form if everything worked fine for me i go on to the next script and so on until the whole application is purely PDO, so to say.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile- I think my comment to PhpDev's question answers yours as well.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing technically prevents you from doing so.

Therefore, for a transition time you can keep two simultaneous connections from your script.

Comment: Just went through your article. Awesome Stuff!

Comment: Great burst of knowledge on two simultaneous connections,Thanks